# Java - Trying to draw an image on each iteration of this forLoop

Tags: java, for-loop, drawing

So I have this forLoop that populates the screen with NavCells. I want to set a background color to each one as they are populated. The main problem is I can't figure out what to set the canvas to for the draw function, if this is even the correct way to go about this.

Cell creating loop:

```
    // creates cells
    mCells = new NavCell[mCellRows][mCellCols];
    //System.out.println( "Rows " + mCellRows + " and Cols: " + mCellCols);
    for (int j = 0; j < mCellRows; j++) {
        System.out.println("inside rows           " + j);
     //   if (mCells[j] != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < mCellCols; i++) {
                System.out.println("inside columns      " + i);

                mCells[j][i] = new NavCell();
                drawCells(null, j, i);
                mCells[j][i].setBounds(
                        i * CELL_SIZE,
                        j * CELL_SIZE,
                        (i * CELL_SIZE) + CELL_SIZE,
                        (i * CELL_SIZE) + CELL_SIZE);


                System.out.println("Hello Matt" + j);




                System.out.println("Lazer-2 " + mCells);
            }
            }
```

Draw method (currently set for an image because setBackground wasn't working)

```
     public void drawCells(Canvas canvas, int X, int Y) {
    mBMPStart = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.start);
    canvas.drawBitmap(mBMPStart, X, Y, null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Time for some drawing refreshers!

Android:
https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/custom-drawing#java

AWT:
https://youtu.be/2l5-5PMUc5Y

You will need to add a way of controlling the drawing iteration, either by adding a button or using a thread containing a repaint call or similar.